# How can I redirect an S3 url using a query string parameter?

Tags: redirect, amazon-s3

I want to redirect the url "http://mydomain.com/s3?file=test" to "http://mydomain.com/s3/test.js" where mydomain.com is an S3 static site.

Based on the docs it doesn't seem possible unless I use a web server but I wonder if there's a way to do this entirely via S3 redirects (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/how-to-page-redirect.html and http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HowDoIWebsiteConfiguration.html).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that by specifying redirection rules while configuring s3 bucket as a static website.

As per your requirement the redirection rules would be:

```
<RoutingRules>
  <RoutingRule>
    <Condition>
      <KeyPrefixEquals>?file=test</KeyPrefixEquals>
    </Condition>
    <Redirect>
      <ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>s3/test.js</ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>
    </Redirect>
  </RoutingRule>
</RoutingRules>
```

hoping it would help

Comment: Is it possible to do it dynamically? Ie file=test1 goes to s3/test1.js, file=test123 goes to s3/test123.js, etc. Or would I have to define a rule for each manually?

Comment: @DanGoldin In that case you could redirect `?file=` to `s3/`. You might also have use for `HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals`.

Comment: I don't think it is working, when I put something as `<KeyPrefixEquals>?file=test&lang=it</KeyPrefixEquals>` S3 returns error as invalid XML. Fortunately, it has own syntax checking.