# 301 Redirect for specific page with CloudFront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I'm rebuilding my website. The new one will be hosted on S3 with CloudFront in front of it.

How do I create a few redirects for some URLs which existed on the old site, but won't on the new site?

`example.com/thing?id=blah` for example I'll be wanting to redirect to `othersite.com/other-path`

Comment: Your example should have both the address you're redirecting from and the address you're trying to redirect to.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't do redirects in CloudFront, but since your origin is S3, you can do redirects in that.

First, you'll need to make sure your CloudFront origin for s3 is configured correctly. You can not do website redirects with the standard REST API (which is the auto-complete option).

> Enter the Amazon S3 static website hosting endpoint for your bucket. This value appears in the Amazon S3 console, on the Properties page under Static Website Hosting.
>
> When you specify the bucket name in this format, you can use Amazon S3 redirects and Amazon S3 custom error documents.

(Source: [Using Amazon S3 Origins and Custom Origins for Web Distributions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/DownloadDistS3AndCustomOrigins.html))

Next, if your redirect-from links do indeed have query parameters in them which you need to evaluate based on, you'll need to [make sure CloudFront is configured to forward query parameters](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html#DownloadDistValuesQueryString). I should note, I've never had to build redirects in s3 that key of query-string parameters, but according to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20959364/how-can-i-redirect-an-s3-url-using-a-query-string-parameter) it should be possible.

> **Forward all, cache based on all**
>
> Choose this option if your origin server returns different versions of your objects for all query string parameters.

(Source: [Query String Forwarding and Caching](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html#DownloadDistValuesQueryString))

Finally, [set up your S3 bucket with Routing Rules](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HowDoIWebsiteConfiguration.html#configure-bucket-as-website-routing-rule-syntax) for the desired redirects. Given your example, it would look something like this:

```
<RoutingRules>
  <RoutingRule>
  <Condition>
    <KeyPrefixEquals>thing?id=blah</KeyPrefixEquals>
  </Condition>
  <Redirect>
    <ReplaceKeyWith>other-path</ReplaceKeyWith>
  </Redirect>
  </RoutingRule>
</RoutingRules>
```

(Source: [Syntax for Specifying Routing Rules](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HowDoIWebsiteConfiguration.html#configure-bucket-as-website-routing-rule-syntax))

The final point to bring to your attention would be the syntax of routing rules themselves. The Condition being placed on your routing rule is `KeyPrefixEquals`. There is no `KeyEquals` Condition available.

This means that if you for example had `thing?id=blah` and `thing?id=blah2` Routing Rules, the order will matter. Put `blah2` before `blah`, or you'll always match on `blah`.

There are many other routing rule options available, that will allow you to change protocol, redirect to another domain instead of just rewriting the path, etc. Check out the [documentation on routing rules](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HowDoIWebsiteConfiguration.html#configure-bucket-as-website-routing-rule-syntax) for more information.

Comment: Very thorough! Thanks, Luke! This is great : ) I'll get to implementing this now...

Comment: I have some redirects that don't require query strings. I've begun with this, but they're not working. I'm just getting my usual 404 page. I wonder if this is because I'm serving my site from the same S3 bucket as I've enabled static site hosting and listed these redirects? Should I be creating a separate bucket for redirects?

Comment: You may need to either: give CF more time to update after changing the origin, or invalidate /*. You definitely want your same bucket, with static site hosting enabled.

Comment: IIRC, 404 would be the behaviour if it wasn't hitting the correct origin. Since the rest API doesn't return the redirects, but the static website hosting does. Try it with the s3 website URL directly to validate your redirects are working there, as a first step.

Comment: I'm invalidating now. I typically set caching to 30 seconds for routes in my dev environment for this reason, but maybe at the Behaviors level something else dictates cache length.

Comment: Okay, so one redirect is working, but another is not, with this error from firefox "Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete."

Comment: Sounds like you might be in a redirect loop on that one? Try `curl -I http://site/path`, then follow the `Location` header with another `curl -I`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143640/discussion-between-costa-and-luke-waite).

Comment: Thank you so much for answering in such detail. The part of forwarding the query string saved me!